# Pass multiple arguments to a function in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I trying to pass the `employeeNum` and `employeePass` to a function called displayButton, it told me that I miss these two arguments.

```
from tkinter import *


def displayButton(root,employNum, employPass):

    Label(root,text = employNum ).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N+S+W+E)
    Label(root, text = employPass).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = N+S+W+E)

def main():

    root = Tk()

    Label(root, text = 'Employee Number: ').grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
    Label(root, text = 'Login Password: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

    employeeNum = StringVar()
    employeePass = StringVar()
    Entry(root, textvariable = employeeNum).grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
    Entry(root, textvariable = employeePass).grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    checkButton = BooleanVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text = 'Remember Me', variable = checkButton).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

    Button(root, text = 'Save', relief = RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E)
    display = Button(root, text = 'Display', relief = RAISED, command = lambda: displayButton(root,employeeNum,employeePass))
    display.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = E)
    display.bind('<Button-1>', displayButton)

    Label(root, text = "Employee's number is ").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
    Label(root, text = "Employee's Passowrd is ").grid(row =4 , column = 0, sticky = W)
    root.mainloop() 

main()
```

The error it gives me is :

```
TypeError: displayButton() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'employNum' and 'employPass'
```

Comment: please post the actual error, and also show how you defined `displayButton`.  As written, you're passing three arguments, which should not give an error about missing arguments if your function does indeed take three arguments.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have edited now.

Comment: We can't run the code you posted, you haven't defined `root` an it's `mainloop`. Edit your post with your full code.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace? Are you sure this error is coming from this button?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have posted the entire file and according to the terminal, it should come from this button because this is the only place I called the displayButton function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to bind the button, so you can remove this line.

```
display.bind('<Button-1>', displayButton)
```

If you are working with `StringVar()` and if you want to read it's content, you have to use `.get()`, `employNum.get()` and `employPass.get()`.

This code should work:

```
from Tkinter import *

def displayButton(root,employNum, employPass):

    Label(root,text = employNum.get() ).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N+S+W+E)
    Label(root, text = employPass.get()).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = N+S+W+E)

def main():

    root = Tk()

    Label(root, text = 'Employee Number: ').grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
    Label(root, text = 'Login Password: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

    employeeNum = StringVar()
    employeePass = StringVar()
    Entry(root, textvariable = employeeNum).grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
    Entry(root, textvariable = employeePass).grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    checkButton = BooleanVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text = 'Remember Me', variable = checkButton).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

    Button(root, text = 'Save', relief = RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E)
    display = Button(root, text = 'Display', relief = RAISED, command = lambda: displayButton(root, employeeNum,employeePass))
    display.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = E)
    #display.bind('<Button-1>', displayButton)

    Label(root, text = "Employee's number is ").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
    Label(root, text = "Employee's Passowrd is ").grid(row =4 , column = 0, sticky = W)
    root.mainloop() 

main()
```